# Ошибка сборки в Code::Blocks на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

Создал проект в Code::Blocks на Ubuntu 16.04. После создания проекта и сборки файла при попытке его запустить возникает ошибка: "It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?". При этом, если нажать "No", запустится консоль, но не выведет того, что должна. Если же нажать "Yes", произойдет еще одна сборка, но при последующих запусках возникнет та же ошибка. Следует отметить, что такая проблема возникает только при создании проекта с названием на русском языке. При создании проекта с английским именем такой ошибки не возникает.

Comment: Здесь http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=138430.0 советуют поставить NetBeans для решения проблемы.

Comment: не надо создавать проект с названием на русском языке?

Comment: @strangeqargo, так вот на винде все в порядке с русским языком

Comment: @hunter, можно, но мне удобно работать именно с Code::Blocks

Comment: какая тебе разница как проект называется тогда? сделай директорию с английским именем, потом будет меньше проблем, если решишь в опенсорс выпустить. Поставь им баг  в багтрекере заодно. Так и напиши "какого епрст, у меня кодировка бога, а вы мне тыкаете путиным в лицо, исправьте быстро", ну на самом деле там наверняка есть такой тикет уже.

Comment: Поддержу @strangeqargo. Не надо применять кириллицу в путях и названиях. А ещё лично я не использую (стараюсь) пробелы, большие буквы, подчёркивания, `$#!%^:;*` и прочие амперсанды. Хотя в linux это всё можно юзать в путях.